# What is the All 1000 scanned ports on X are in ignore states in NMAP mean

Tags: networking, port, nmap

We are using the NMAP 7.92 version.

When we run: `nmap -sT XX.XX.XX`

It returned:

> Nmap scan report for XX.XX.XX.XX Host is up (0.31s latency).
> All 1000 scanned ports on XX.XX.XX.XX are in ignored states.
> Not shown: 1000 filtered tcp ports (no-response)
>
> Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 318.39 seconds

What does this are in ignored states means? Does it mean closed like the old version? We are a bit lost on this.

Comment: it means that in the lower 1000 ports, all of the ports sent no information about the port state. from a given perspective all ports will either have a process listening on them or will be closed. a closed port is identified by either a reject message during TCP handshake (in which case the initiator is notified of the rejection) or by timeout (the target host ignored the connection attempt and sent no traffic to the initiator). of the two, ignoring is more secure than rejection, as a rejection may indicate that under other circumstances the port to be open.

Answer (score 0):

Per NMAP.org book:

> Ignored State field
>
> Example: Ignored State: filtered (1658)
>
> To save space, Nmap may omit ports in one non-open state from the list
> in the Ports field. Nmap does this in interactive output too. Regular
> Nmap users are familiar with the lines such as Not shown: 993 closed
> ports. For grepable mode, that state is given in the Ignored State
> field. Following the state name is a space, then in parentheses is the
> number of ports found in that state.

Closed ports aren't offering information so this should speed up in finding useful data. So no service are replying to request to talk from Nmap. Try using different port scanning techniques and see if you getting any useful information ( -sS -sU -sY -sN -sF -sX ....)

https://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-techniques.html

Let us know if this helped answer your question.